# Event listener for appended html elements not working

Tags: jquery, jsp

The event listener for my appended html elements are not working. What this button does is that it will open up a popup that prompts user for delete confirmation.

I'm doing the view page this way instead of the normal html and jsp code way because I want to make use of ajax and jquery for pagination. The event listener works properly back then. I've omitted out the code because its not very relevant.

What am I doing wrong?

viewAnnouncements.jsp

```
<table>
<thead>
    <!--Sets the table headings-->
</thead>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function() {
        $.get("processPagination.jsp?requestType=getRecords, function(data) {
            var JSONData = JSON.parse(data);
            for(i=0; i<recordsToFetch; i++){
            const record = JSONData.results[i].split(",");
            const title = record[0];
            $("tbody").append("
            <tr>
                <td><a>"+title+"</a></td>
                <td>
                    <p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete'>
                    <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs announcement-delete-button' data-title='Delete' data-id='"+index+"'>
                    <i class='far fa-trash-alt' ></i></button></p>
                </td>
            </tr>");
            }
    });
</script>
<tbody>
    <!--Rows are appended here-->
</tbody>
```

main.js

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.announcement-delete-button').on('click', function() {
        const id =  $(this).data().id;
        $('.grey-screen').show();
        $('#announcement-delete').fadeIn();
        $('.announcement-delete-yes')
            .attr("onclick", 
            "window.location.href='/testweb/announcementController?Submit=delete
        );
    });
});
```

EDIT: I have already tried binding the event listener to tbody and calling for the child selector 'announcement-delete-button' and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind event listener to body instead of direct class

```
$('body').on('click', '.announcement-delete-button', function (e) { /*Your code here*/ });
```

Comment: by body you mean the tbody?

Comment: by body I mean the document body, see the code in answer

Comment: Does the parent have to be a direct parent?

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to say here. What parent ?

Comment: Wow, i did it, I was probably binding to a wrong html parent the whole time. Thanks alot!

Comment: @ClementOng please mark the question as accepted

Answer (score 0):

in this case you only have to restrict the strings and add them together at the time of the append

```
$("tbody").append("" +
        "<tr>" +
        "    <td><a>"+title+"</a></td>" +
        "    <td>" +
        "       <p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete'>" +
        "        <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs announcement-delete-button' data-title='Delete' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#delete' data-id='"+index+"'>" +
        "        <i class='far fa-trash-alt' ></i></button></p>" +
        "    </td>" +
        "</tr>");
```

Comment: The appending part is not the one causing me the trouble, I was able to view the rows with all my data in the table no problem. Problem was with the event listener attached to the announcement-delete-button class –

Comment: okay, in this case idk